# How can I get the entire histogram in a 5 qubit program done in IBM quantum experience machine?

Tags: programming, ibm-q-experience

I have run a program on an IBM quantum experience machine which involves 5 qubits. Obviously when I measure the whole system I have 32 results but the machine only represents 20 in the histogram. In this situation the program tells you to download the results. The problem is that when I pick "Download PNG" or "Download SVG" it continues to show me a 20 results histogram. There is another option that is to pick "Download results" but it downloads two *.json* documents which I'm not sure I know how to change into a histogram.

Answer (score 5):

By clicking on Downloand you get two .json files as you mentioned. The results are saved in the file with suffix *results*.

When you open the file in Notepad or any other text editor, you can find results in this form:

```
"results":[{"data":{"counts":{"0x0":28,"0x1":39,"0x10":35,"0x11":28,"0x12":25,"0x13":32,"0x14":22,"0x15":36,"0x16":42,"0x17":33,"0x18":35,"0x19":23,"0x1a":34,"0x1b":24,"0x1c":29,"0x1d":43,"0x1e":34,"0x1f":31,"0x2":37,"0x3":32,"0x4":31,"0x5":33,"0x6":39,"0x7":35,"0x8":37,"0x9":29,"0xa":29,"0xb":25,"0xc":30,"0xd":29,"0xe":40,"0xf":25}},
```

States which are described by binary numbers in the graph on the result page in IBM Q interface are here described by hexadecimal numbers and showed together with number of occurences, for example:

```
"0x13":32
```

This means that value $13_{16}=19_{10}=10011_2$ occured 32 times.

You can extract these data from .json file manually, change hexadecimal numbers to binary and plot a histogram. For example, you can do it in Excel - hexadecimal numbers can be converted to binary ones with function *HEX2BIN* and then you can use bar graph instead of histogram.

Comment: It's much easier to convert hexadecimal directly to binary rather than going through decimal. Each hexadecimal digit expands into four binary digits, e.g. `3` becomes `0011`.

Comment: @CJDennis: Yes, you are right. I have just shown an example and in Excel I used HEX2BIN function, of course.